# Not getting current latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, location

In my application I am not getting the current latitue and longitude

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    LocationListener {
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
TextView txtLat;
String lat;
String provider;
protected String latitude, longitude;
protected boolean gps_enabled, network_enabled;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.google_map_send_my_current_latlong);
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:"
            + location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude", "disable");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude", "enable");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("Latitude", "status");
}
   }
```

and my Manifest I added

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I want to show my current latitude and longitude in TextView. I checked on Real device

Comment: It takes time to get a GPS lock.  It can be seconds to minutes (or never if you're indoors).  It also won't work if the GPS is off.  Have you tried it outside (somewhere where Google maps works) with GPS on?

Comment: My GPS is On, and I checked around two minutes.

Comment: The GPS symbol in the notification bar-  was it flashing or solid?  If it was flashing you did not have a lock.  (if it wasn't there at all, that's another problem).

Comment: It is flashing continuously

Comment: That means you don't have a GPS lock.  Try going outside, away from tall buildings.  Your code looks right to me, but the satelite signal from GPS is something we can't control

Comment: OK. I will check. Thnx for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving simple and effective code for getting latitude and longitude of the current location and will give best result; first it will see satellite location than INTERNET location than Sim location and give message if not found anything...It will give location on moving also:

```
package selecom.loc;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
//don't implents LocationListner if you wants only latitude and longitude 
//only at a time

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
LocationManager locationManager;
TextView tvLatitude, tvLongitude;
String provider;
Location location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvLongitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lng);
    tvLatitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lat);

    locationManager =(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria c=new Criteria(); 
    //if we pass false than
    //it will check first satellite location than Internet and than Sim Network
    provider=locationManager.getBestProvider(c, false);
    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(location!=null)
    {
        double lng=location.getLongitude();
        double lat=location.getLatitude();
        tvLongitude.setText(""+lng);
        tvLatitude.setText(""+lat);
    }
    else
    {
        tvLongitude.setText("No Provider");
        tvLatitude.setText("No Provider");
    }
}
 //The below methods can be removed if you don't want location on move
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) 
{
    double lng =location.getLongitude();
    double lat=location.getLatitude();
    tvLongitude.setText(""+lng);
    tvLatitude.setText(""+lat);   
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {  
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {   
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

call this method in your onCreate() method and  check if it works for you

```
public Location getLocation(){

    try {
        locMan=(LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled=locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled=locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(isGPSEnabled||isNetworkEnabled)
        {
            canGetLocation=true;
            if(isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, DIST,this);
                if(locMan!=null)
                {
                    loc=locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if(loc!=null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "loac", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        latitude=loc.getLatitude();
                        longitude=loc.getLongitude();
                        LocationLogic.getInstance().setLat(latitude);
                        LocationLogic.getInstance().setLang(longitude);

                    }
                }

            }
            if(isGPSEnabled&&loc==null)
            {
                locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, DIST,this);
                if(locMan!=null)
                {
                    loc=locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if(loc!=null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "loac", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        latitude=loc.getLatitude();
                        longitude=loc.getLongitude();
                        LocationLogic.getInstance().setLat(latitude);
                        LocationLogic.getInstance().setLang(longitude);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    double d=distTo(latitude, longitude, 31.3256, 75.5792);
    setDist(d);
    //  doReverseGeoCodingTask(loc);
        Log.i("done","done");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return loc;

}
```

Also add these permissions in your manifest file :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Hope this will work for you. Make sure you have your either GPS or internet switched on.